# Regex matching only uppercase not working

Tags: regex, splunk

I have written a regex to use in Splunk which should only match log levels in the following form

```
[ERROR]
[INFO ]
[DEBUG]
```

It works fine but for some reason it also includes lowercase elements (like `[info]`). This is the regex:

```
(?i) .*?\] \[(?P<FIELDNAME>[A-Z]+\s?)(?=\])
```

Am I not explicitly stating that I only want to consider elements containing uppercase characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `(?i)` modifier from your pattern. `(?i)` modifier in a pattern does a case-insensitive match.